# Can m3u8 files have mp4 file urls?

Tags: html, video, nginx, ffmpeg, jwplayer

I am in a situation where I have my flv video converted to mp4 and then I am streaming this as http url using my nginx server. For multibitrate supoport on html5 I have created a m3u8 file like this :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=200111, RESOLUTION=512x288
http://streamer.abc.com:8080/videos/arvind1.mp4
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3000444, RESOLUTION=400x300
http://streamer.abc.com:8080/videos/arvind1.mp4
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=400777, RESOLUTION=400x300
http://streamer.abc.com:8080/videos/arvind1.mp4
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

But jwplayer is not playing this saying playlist not loaded. Specifically "No playable sources found". Please help.

Comment: Do you have a link? Please note, HLS on the desktop requires a premium license for the JW Player.

Comment: Oh! is that so ? I was trying to play that in my free version. I was in an urgent situation so for the time being I have configured my nginx with rtmp module and things are working fine. Using smil as of now with jwplayer. Will look on premium jwplayer soon.

Comment: And also please let me know why mmy question has been marked as negative.

Comment: Indeed, you need a premium JW Player edition for HLS on the desktop, as HLS in html5 <video> only works on the desktop in Safari on OS X. We play HLS streams using Flash on other desktop browsers. You still can't use use MP4 in HLS though, I am fairly certain.

Comment: Others marked it down, I believe for lack of info / not programming related.

Comment: Okay, from next time, will post it to video.stackexchange.com. Thanks for replying @EthanJWPlayer . Currently, I moved to rtmp with nginx configured in smil and it worked fine . Will work on hls soon when I get free.

Comment: No problem, any time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, HLS only supports segmented transport streams in an m3u8 playlist. You may find it to works in some players, but it is not part of the standard, and will not work in iOS.

Comment: Umm Okay, is there any other way that I can play my mp4 files of mutibitrates to get played as per user's bandwidth! I can do that with smil with rtmp urls (I did currently) . Please help, I want to move away from flash to html5 mostly.

Comment: Look into media source extensions and DASH.

Answer (score 0):

It works with me as:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1
http://streamer.abc.com:8080/videos/arvind1.mp4
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```